# How to run C# Console Applications via Python?

Tags: python, c#, console-application

I've created the following **C# Console Application (.NET Core 3.1)** with Visual Studio:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            //Check if args contains anything
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("args = " + args[0]);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("args is empty");
            }

            //Prevent the application from closing itself without user input
            string waiter = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to execute the application succesfully with one argument via **cmd.exe**:
[CMD Input and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FKil.png)

Now I'd like to run this program with one argument via **Python**. I've read [How to execute a program or call a system command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command) and tried to implement it. However, it seems that the application is not being run properly.

The python code I am using via Jupyter notebook:

```
import subprocess
path = "C:/Users/duykh/source/repos/ConsoleApp2/ConsoleApp2/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/ConsoleApp2.exe"
subprocess.Popen(path) //#Also tried with .call and .run
                        //#subprocess.Popen([path, "argumentexample"]) doesn't work either
```

Output:

```
<subprocess.Popen at 0x2bcaeba49a0>
```

My question would be:

**Why is it not being run (properly) and how do I properly run this application with one argument?**

Comment: Maybe another option is to call/run shell or cmd from Python and run the application from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my own question. In a nutshell: I am pretty stupid.

1. Jupyter Notebook was running in the background and the application was being run there. That's why it didn't open a new prompt.
2. `subprocess.Popen([path, "argument example"])` seems to work well for running a console application with an argument as input.